# formBuilder is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, formbuilder

## Description:

- I have used the Form Builder library for react based on your documentation. I have previously built a feature for one of my projects where I wanted custom fields and not the predefined ones. However I was able to achieve it as it was react based on simple JavaScript(.js extension).
- Now I have to achieve the same functionality in my another project which is based on Vite + TS and I am unable to get the result and the error that is thrown is formBuilder is not a function. The same code which I have used in .js file(my other project) does not work here and behaves weirdly.
- I have also tried to configure my latest project such that it can support js/jsx configurations but at the end I end up with the same error.

Here is the code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
if (fb.current) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setFormBuilder(
      $('#form-builder-area').formBuilder({
        ...options,
        fields,
      })
    );
  }, 5000);
}
```

}, [fields, options]);

- **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formBuilder is not a function**
- This error pops up and also it crashes the application if I do not use .ready method of jQuery or do not put it in setTimeout.

## Steps to Reproduce

- Setup a project with MUI theme with the latest versions of React JS and Vite.
- Use the library and try to make the fields dynamic.

Here are the resources you might need to look into this issue:

- Form Builder - https://formbuilder.online/
- Form Builder Repo - https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder
- Form Builder npm link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/formBuilder

I have mentioned the actual and the expected behaviour in the description itself.

Comment: You've written this like a bug report to the library author. As such I would suggest you post it on the github repo you linked to. This site is for debugging issues with code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have mentioned the code now. I did not do it before because I don't think it is something where the error is arising from. However the whole file is a bit large because I have implemented a custom logic for the options I want to pass with form builder. I have tried using ref initially and also I have loaded the script properly using the $.ready() method.

Comment: This error would suggest that the `formBuilder` script is not loaded correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from the authors. Posting a link here!!!
https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder/issues/1509#issuecomment-1952435414